# Charlie Stigler and other random items running in the background?

Tags: macos, launchd, settings, file, login-items

I have a `MacBook Pro` with `macOS Ventura 13.0`.

In System Settings -> General -> Login Items, I discovered that a random `Charlie Stigler` item was running in the background. I have no idea what this is. Please give more information about this and advise whether I should let it continue to run in the background.

I have also found `eudataback` and `OSMessageTracer` items from **unidentified developers** which are supposedly running in the background. These files are located at the following path: -

**Eudataback Pathway location**: -

> /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.easeus.dataprotectbackup.plist

**OSMessageTracer Pathway location**: -

> /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.installer.osmessagetracing.plist

Can some please suggest whether to give permissions to the following items mentioned above to run in the background or not?

Here are the following pictures for your reference: -

[image: Charlie Stigler Item?]

[image: Eudataback Item?]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

What you have discovered is one of the disaster areas for the new System Settings. Obviously copied from the iOS Settings without enough care and attention. On macOS this list of background apps is bound to confuse users and raise often unwarranted fears.

Just to clear up a minor confusion. Items in the list are those *allowed* to run in the background. This list does not indicate that they are running.

Charlie Stigler is likely the developer of an app you have installed. This name appears because it is associated with the digital certificate signing the background app. You will need to use web searches to discover what apps Charlie Stigler has created. My best guess is this [Charlie Stigler](https://charliestigler.com) who has an app called SelfControl.

For 'eudataback' there is (as you have discovered) an information button which locates the background app in Finder. That gives the hint that it is part of the [Easus Backup Software](https://www.easeus.com/backup-software/).

Very likely all your background apps are legitimate.

But note that they could include apps that you uninstalled in past by just deleting the app in /Applications without discovering and removing associated files and tasks.

Apple will need to do something to cleanup the "Allow in the Background" list so that the parent app is correctly displayed.  This may be difficult where the parent app has been deleted but the background tasks have not.

It seems downright sloppy that Apple has not tidied things up their own background tasks. I don't have OSMessageTracer Pathway in my list, but I am pretty sure this is legitimate. Possibly it a remnant from an earlier version of macOS - see [Is OSMessageTracing in Startup Login Items Legitimate](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254334032)?

I do have `com.apple.bluetooth.PacketLoggerHelper` in my list.

I will end with an example on my Mac showing that it may not be easy to track down all legitimate items. I have a background app labeled as "PhotoMinds LLC". I do know that this is legitimate, but it is not for a photography app, it is for Arq Backup from Haystack Software.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. SelfControl app was indeed downloaded by me ages ago and also have been subsequently deleted a long time back. I must point out though that I have never used EaseUS app. Anyways, is there any way I can manually tidy things up and delete the associated files and tasks of uninstalled applications?

Comment: App Cleaner (free) https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/ is the most popular app for uninstalling apps.  But is does need the app to be installed.  I suggest, download and install SelfControl, then use App Cleaner to uninstall. That should clean it all out. For EaseUS (probably installed with something else and not told you!) it is likely sufficient to just delete (more to trash) /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.easeus.dataprotectbackup.plist (that is the system library, not your ~/Library) and reboot.